# JQuery Mobile. Was working, but now has a bug

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an app that uses `jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.js`. The script has worked every time, but now when I try it there is a 1 in 3 chance that I will get this error:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer is undefined
[Break On This Error] $.mobile.pageContainer.addClass(className);
```

I have added the origional version and tried again, but I still get the error (line 2425)

Is there any JQuery Mobile version I get that will be error free? Again this error is in the mobile file, and not my code (`jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.js`)

**Edit** I get the same issue when I use the min version as well `jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js`

Comment: When do you get that error? On initial page load? Have you tried 1.0b1 ?

Comment: I got the same thing on the beta. I moved where the scripts were downloaded around, and created an eq to document.ready. that seemed to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"1 in 3 chance" to me sounds like you have a race condition based on the download times of your scripts.  You may want to look at firing custom events when everything is downloaded and ready to go instead of having a downloaded script immediately executing.

Comment: That's a good point.  It looks like JQuery Mobile doesn't have a document.ready method, but you could look into this solution: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-equivalent-of-document-ready

Comment: Adding a method call at the very bottom of my page seemed to clear it up (from what I can tell now). I am hoping that was the issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's no `document.ready()` method as such (although you can use one, kind of), but jQM has its own page events to work with instead. You should bear in mind that "pages" may actually be a load of divs in one physical html file, with navigation happening via the `location.hash`. You probably simply need to experiment with the event that gives the best results (and ensure that all referenced code is in scope with regards the original "page" in your content model).

Answer (score 0):

> Again this error is in the mobile file, and not my code

The error is being reported in the JQuery mobile code, but it could be caused by an error in your script.  Try creating a simple test script that uses JQuery mobile to see if you still get the error.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you still link to the correct JQuery.js file and that's still up.

It's always best to download a working JQuery script and host it on your own server though. So no changes will ever be made to it.

As for your question if there are other JQuery Mobile versions, I'm sure there are.. But that's what [Google](http://www.google.com) will help you with.

Comment: It's not always best.  There are plenty of reasons to use a CDN instead of your own server.

Comment: @Dan H I agree, but I have experienced CDN going down before for a few hours, which screwed up all the pages I was using JQuery on. Which was a HUGE issue obviously, for all the website visitors. So we missed out on a lot of sales that day.

Comment: That's true but unless you have a high-availability configuration with redundant power and connectivity, your server is more likely to go down than the typical CDN provider.

Comment: But if your server goes down, the CDN is of no importance anyway... As your website cannot even be reached anymore.

Comment: True, but you'd still be missing out on sales.  It's not a panacea, but there are significant advantages to using a CDN.